# Unable to specify route in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am using visual studio to setup a small project. But there is no `app_start` folder so I can make changes to routeconfig file. There is a `program.cs` file where it contained the routecontroller, but there is no effect on it. The default method still remains `Index`.

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Read",
    pattern: "{controller=Read}/{action=Welcome}/{id?}");
```

So I created a folder with routeconfig file, but it doesn't recognizes the ignore route method and unable to run it.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace SecondProject
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Hi Jackdaw, its saying target framework .net 6.0

Comment: .NET 6.0 - this means you are using ASP.NET Core MVC. See link to the documentation below how to implement routing in the ASP.NET Core MVC. [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0). You don't need to create the `public class RouteConfig` in your case. It used in the ASP.NET Framework MVC. What problem you face when removing the `public class RouteConfig`? __By the way you are defining two `MapControllerRoute` with identical pattern. You can remove the second: it will never work.__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fit to a comment. Therefore, I put it as an answer.

Your question contains parts of code related to different versions of the ASP.NET. The first related to the ASP.NET Core MVC and the second for ASP.NET Framework MVC. **These are different version with different routing implementation.**
You should use the correct template when you build your project - this depend on your requirements.

The question is: **Which version you are using?**

If your project doesn't contain `app_start` folder, but contains  `program.cs` file this means that you are using  ASP.NET Core MVC. Then look at the documentation hot to implement routing in your application: [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

---

To make the `Welcome` action method as the default remove the first route template declaration and leave only the `"Read"` pattern:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Read",
    pattern: "{controller=Read}/{action=Welcome}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Hi, I went throught the documentation, added the following route, app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Read",
    pattern: "Read",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Welcome" });  -- it still uses index as default method. Can you please say what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Hi, You are defining routes with identical pattern: the second will never work. What action method you want to use as the default? If you want to use action `Welcome` as the default then remove the first route template declaration.

Comment: Hey, Welcome method as in default for this one

Comment: Just remove route pattern named `"default"` and you will use `Welcome` action method as the default and the default controller is `Read`.